# On equal area planar sections of 3D convex bodies

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-geometry

This is an extension of [On segments of equal area cut from planar convex regions by chords](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457094/on-segments-of-equal-area-cut-from-planar-convex-regions-by-chords).

While the 3D analog of the above question would be about 3D pieces cut from a convex body $C$ by planes, here we ask about *planar sections*.

**Question:** Other than the solid sphere, is there any 3D convex body of unit volume $C$ with the property: all equal area planar sections of $C$ with even one specified area $\alpha$ also have the same perimeter (we refer here to the area and perimeter of the section itself)?

As pointed out by Jukka Kohonen below, when the area of cross section $\alpha$ is maximal, examples of such solids do exist; so the question probably ought to really focus on *non-maximal* values of $\alpha$.

And does this question have any connection to surfaces of constant width or  bodies of const brightness? Another earlier post in the same ballpark:  [A claim on planar sections of 3D convex bodies](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450310/a-claim-on-planar-sections-of-3d-convex-bodies).

**Note:** we could replace "equal perimeter" with "equal diameter" or say, "are at equal perpendicular distance from some point" etc... (in general, " all sections with quantity A also having quantity B equal") to get other questions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with the unit cube and $\alpha = \sqrt{2}$, which is the maximum possible area of a cross-section. This area is attained *only* with rectangles with two sides of length $1$ (coinciding with the cube's edges) and two sides of length $\sqrt{2}$. So perforce those cross-sections have the same perimeter, namely $2+2\sqrt{2}$.

There are six such rectangles, so the solution is not trivial in the sense of having only one unique maximal-area cross section. I guess there would be other shapes with a similar situation, if you set $\alpha$ to be the maximal cross-section area. If $\alpha$ is not maximal, the question becomes more challenging.

That the area $\sqrt{2}$ is maximal in the unit cube, and only attained by these rectangles, follows from Ball's theorem:

> Every section of the unit cube, $Q_n$, by an $(n-1)$-dimensional
> subspace, $H$, has volume at most $\sqrt{2}$. This upper bound is
> attained if and only if $H$ contains an $(n-2)$-dimensional face of
> $Q_n$.

*Ball, Keith*, [**Cube slicing in $\mathbf{R}^ n$**](https://doi.org/10.2307/2046239), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 97, 465-473 (1986). [ZBL0601.52005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0601.52005).

Comment: Thanks.  What I had in mind were indeed values of alpha such that a convex body has infinitely many cross sections with same area alpha. I guess what you showed by example is a sort of extreme - say degenerate - situation. Indeed, even in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457094/on-segments-of-equal-area-cut-from-planar-convex-regions-by-chords, the comment by Pierre about centrally symmetric planar regions indicates a similar situation I guess.

Comment: For a continuum of sections, consider the right circular cylinder of diameter $10$ and height $1$. The largest cross-sections would be the ellipses that touch each base at a point; since they are congruent, they have the same perimeter. Perhaps you want to restrict $\alpha$ to be nonmaximal, or perhaps you want incongruent cross sections?

Comment: Thanks again. It probably needs to be mentioned that alpha is non-maximal; shall edit question. There seems to be any need to insist that the cross sections should be incongruent but the non-maximality of alpha is I think important.